# Getting incorrect hard disk serial number with Non-Admin user in Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, serial-number

In laptops having type samsung NVMe, we are getting incorect hard disk serial number, so for this we have used StorageDeviceUniqueIdProperty instead of StorageDeviceProperty .

But in some windows physical machine, we are getting wrong offset as we have not typecast the buffer but if we typecast the buffer to STORAGE_DEVICE_ID_DESCRIPTOR instead of STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR then I don't have any member in structure to return the offset value.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <winioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <Storduid.h>
//#include <storduid.h>
//#include <errno.h>


int ReadPhysicalDriveInNT_StorageQuery (char *deviceName, char *realDiskID, int diskid_len)
{
   int retCode = 1;
   STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY query;
   DWORD cbBytesReturned = 0;
   char buffer [20000] = {'\0'};
   HANDLE hPhysicalDriveIOCTL = 0;
   //STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR * descrip = NULL;
   STORAGE_DEVICE_ID_DESCRIPTOR * descrip = NULL;

   char serialNumber [128] = {'\0'};
   int i = 0;
   int OSVersion=0;
   int status=0;
   BOOL isWin8 = 0;
   int retry_count = 0;
   
   status = GetOsVersion(&OSVersion); 

    hPhysicalDriveIOCTL = CreateFile (TEXT(deviceName), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

   if(hPhysicalDriveIOCTL == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
      printf("ReadPhysicalDriveInNT_StorageQuery ERROR:"
             " CreateFile(%s) returned INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE\n"
             , deviceName);
      goto ERR_EXIT;
   }

   memset ((void *) & query, 0, sizeof (query));
   query.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;
   query.PropertyId = StorageDeviceUniqueIdProperty;
   //query.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;

RETRY:
   memset (buffer, 0, sizeof (buffer));
   cbBytesReturned = 0;

   /*we have set the PropertyId as StorageDeviceUniqueIdProperty which is not supported before Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008,
   so, if it fails then set the PropertyId to StorageDeviceProperty*/
   if (!DeviceIoControl(hPhysicalDriveIOCTL, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
                        & query,
                        sizeof (query),
                        & buffer,
                        sizeof (buffer)-1,
                        & cbBytesReturned, NULL))
   {
       if(query.PropertyId == StorageDeviceProperty)
           goto ERR_EXIT;

       query.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;
       goto RETRY; 
   }
          
   printf("\ncbBytesReturned - %d\n\n and buffer is ", cbBytesReturned);
   for(i=0; i< cbBytesReturned; i++)
   {
      printf("%c", buffer[i]);
   }      
   printf("-----\n\n");
          
   //descrip =   (STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR *) & buffer;
   descrip = (STORAGE_DEVICE_ID_DESCRIPTOR *) & buffer;
 
   printf("version :%d\n", descrip->Version);
   printf("size :%d\n", descrip->Size);
   printf("NumberOfIdentifiers :%d\n", descrip->NumberOfIdentifiers);

   /*printf("case 2: serialnumberoffset %d\n", descrip->SerialNumberOffset);
     VLMremoveLeadingSpaces(buffer + descrip->SerialNumberOffset);
     flipAndCodeBytes (buffer,
                        descrip -> SerialNumberOffset,
                        0, serialNumber );*/

   printf("\nserial number : %s\n\n", serialNumber);
   strcpy (realDiskID, serialNumber);
   retCode = 0;

ERR_EXIT:

   CloseHandle (hPhysicalDriveIOCTL);

    return retCode;
}

int main()
{

    char dname[256] = {0};
    char diskID[64];
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<4;i++)
    {
      sprintf(dname, "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive%d", i);
      dname[strlen(dname)] = '\0';
      ReadPhysicalDriveInNT_StorageQuery(dname, diskID, sizeof(diskID));
    }

return 0;
}
```

so, is there any way to get the correct offset while using StorageDeviceUniqueIdProperty asPropertyId;

Comment: When you read StorageDeviceUniqueIdProperty, the buffer is of STORAGE_DEVICE_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/storduid/ns-storduid-_storage_device_unique_identifier

Comment: Tried with STORAGE_DEVICE_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER  but not getting valid offset value.

Comment: Perhaps `STORAGE_DEVICE_ID_DESCRIPTOR::Identifiers` is a solution to retrieve SerialNumberOffset.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo, STORAGE_DEVICE_ID_DESCRIPTOR structure does not have any member to retrieve the offset.

typedef struct _STORAGE_DEVICE_ID_DESCRIPTOR {
  ULONG Version;
  ULONG Size;
  ULONG NumberOfIdentifiers;
  UCHAR Identifiers[1];
}

Comment: @Ashish Durgapal On *Memory* window, you can find the serial number at *STORAGE_DEVICE_ID_DESCRIPTOR*'s **Identifiers** field area.