# hard disk serial returned from DeviceIoControl and STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER is empty or has spaces before actual serial

Tags: c++, winapi, disk

I could get the serial using WMI in a win32 application but I'm working now in a windows service and having problems with WMI so I tried to use DeviceIoControl for PhysicalDrive0 to get the serial number. I looked at some sites online and cam with this function:

```
std::string get_hard_disk_serial_string()
{
    // file is a wrapper for HANDLE and CreateFile.
    file drive_file{ L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", open_mode::existing, access::read, share_mode::read | share_mode::write };

    STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY query{};
    query.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;
    query.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;

    auto ioctl_size = [&]() -> uint32_t
    {
        STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER header{};
        DWORD bytes_returned = 0;
        BOOL ret = ::DeviceIoControl(drive_file.native_handle().get(), IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &query,
            sizeof(query), &header, sizeof(header), &bytes_returned, nullptr);
        if (!ret)
            throw std::system_error(GetLastError(), std::system_category());
        return header.Size;
    };

    std::vector<char> out_buff;
    out_buff.resize(ioctl_size());

    [&]
    {
        DWORD bytes_returned = 0;
        BOOL ret = ::DeviceIoControl(drive_file.native_handle().get(), IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &query,
            sizeof(query), out_buff.data(), static_cast<DWORD>(out_buff.size()), &bytes_returned, nullptr);
        if (!ret)
            throw std::system_error(GetLastError(), std::system_category());
    }();

    STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR* descriptor = reinterpret_cast<STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR*>(out_buff.data());
    if (!descriptor->SerialNumberOffset || descriptor->SerialNumberOffset >= out_buff.size())
    {
        printf("serial offset is 0 or greater than buffer size !\n");
        return "";
    }
    // serial is null terminated ansi string
    std::string_view serial = &out_buff[descriptor->SerialNumberOffset];
    printf("disk serial: %s\n", serial.data()); // prints spaces before serial or an empty serial !
    return std::string{ serial };
}
```

The problem is that on one computer running windows 10 the serial contained spaces before the actual serial " SERIAL-HERE" and on another one which runs windows server 2012 R2 the serial was totally empty !

Comment: Who are you to decide that spaces are not valid in a serial number? There is no standard for what these are.

Comment: [Can *StorageDeviceIdProperty* retrieve the serial number properly on windows server 2012 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503522/getting-incorrect-hard-disk-serial-number-with-non-admin-user-in-windows)

Comment: @Anders WMI method returns no spaces